# Accessing database via Laravel tasks

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a Laravel Task using artisan with the aim of running a cron script. I was able to create the task and perform input / output etc via the CLI.

I would also like to access the DB layer within the fire() of the task. When I specify something like:

```
Client::where('active','=',1)->get();
```

I receive an error "call to undefined method client::where()".

Would like to know how I could run database related commands via the Task

Regards,

Comment: Could the problem be that there are several `Client` classes within the framework and other dependencies?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Even If I try to access another model it gives the same error

Comment: Hmmm. What do you get if you try `Client::all()`?

Comment: And the models can be used normal in controllers etc?

Comment: yes, I have a larger application built on top of the framework with no issues accessing models

Comment: Strange. I just tried to reproduce it and everything worked without a problem. Can you make create a new instance? `$client = new Client;` and if that works check `if($client instanceof '\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model')`

Comment: Make sure you don't have a migration called `Client`.